# Warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry

Tags: c, visual-studio

У меня возникла проблема с работой Visual Studio 2013. При попытке компиляции проекта сперва появляется сообщение

> Следующий проект устарел. Выполнить его сборку?

Пытаюсь выполнить сборку, но возникает ошибка  "

> Предупреждение 1 warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry. TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.

За ней следует

> Ошибка 2 error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "kernel32.lib

И компиляции не происходит. Что нужно делать в данной ситуации? ОС - Windows 7, 32 bit. Спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main {
    cout << "Hello!/n";
}
```

*Обновление*

Поясню. Я сделал следующее: скачал Visual Studio 2013, установил на ноутбук, запустил, написал простой код с `#include <iostream>`, запустил - появились ошибки. kernel32.lib в коде я не подключал, если Вы это имеете ввиду. Но она появилась в логе с ошибками.

*Обновление 2*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    cout << "Hello!/n";
}
```

Comment: Установить SDK?

С другой стороны, если вы сознательно используете `kernel32.lib` в проекте, почему вы спрашиваете? Вы должны сами всё прекрасно знать.

Если вы используете `kernel32.lib` не зная, что это такое и зачем, значит это вам не нужно, выкиньте его, и дело с концом.

Comment: Я только начинаю учиться в ИТ-академии. Я не знаю, для чего нужна kernel32.lib. Все, что мне нужно, - чтобы Visual компилировал мой код. Спасибо за ответ. Попробую проследовать Вашему совету ;)

Comment: @Chealeak: эээ... А откуда она тогда взялась в вашем коде?

ЗЫ: после установки SDK не забудьте перегрузить Visual Studio

Comment: @Chealeak: Хм. Странно. Дайте код, проверю у себя.

Comment: У вас на компьютере только 2013 студия? 2010 случайно нет? (не заметил что вопрос старый)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо

```
void main
```

написать

```
int main ()
```

(главное -- это скобочки после слова `main`).

--

И *книжку* про язык (это С++) почитайте.

Comment: Я знаю про скобки. Проста сейчас на работе. Наспех забыл поставить. Мои ошибки не из-за кода - это точно. Я другие проекты открываю (готовые и правильные) - то же самое. С программой что-то. Поставлю этот SDK. Надеюсь, вылечит)

Comment: SDK не помог... Кстати, если на запрос о сборке проекта ответить "нет", появляется черное окно с сообщением: "Системе не удается найти указанный путь".

Comment: @Chealeak, да, это явно проблема с установкой MS софта.

Сам-то я на винде использую MinGW, так что видимо ничего дельного (кроме "снести все и перустановить с параметрами по-умолчанию") посоветовать не смогу.

Comment: Думаю, поставлю старую версию - 2010. Она работала. Зря ее снес)) Спасибо за помощь!